# Go-zabbix library does not find existing Event by id

Tags: go, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am trying to get an `Event` with a given `event_id` from Zabbix via the library `github.com/cavaliercoder/go-zabbix`.
An event with this id exists and is currently active. Connection to Zabbix is successful. Moreover, if I remove the `EventIDs` filter, it finds more than 600 events. But (!) I cannot access some of them directly from the Zabbix web interface under the same user.

*Code:*

```
session, err := zabbix.NewSession("zabbix_url/api_jsonrpc.php", "user", "password")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var event_ids []string = []string{"2589270"}
params := zabbix.EventGetParams{
    EventIDs:               event_ids,
}
events, err := session.GetEvents(params)
fmt.Println(events)
```

*Output:*

```
[]
```

*Errors:*

```
2021/07/06 18:49:09 Error getting events: No results were found matching the given search 
parameters
2021/07/06 18:49:09 No events found
2021/07/06 18:49:09 Validated 0 Events
```

Maybe I somehow incorrectly enter the `id` in the library?

In the source code of the library, the `EventIDs` parameter looks like this:

```
EventIDs []string `json:"eventids,omitempty"`
```

At the same time, everything works correctly from curl.

**UPD**

 Code:

```
jparams, err := json.Marshal(params)
os.Stdout.Write(jparams)
```

Returns:

```
{"eventids":["2589270"],"object":0,"acknowledged":false}
```

**UPD2:**

It has been empirically established that the problem lies in the `acknowledged` parameter. If it is set to `false`, the event is not found. If it is set to `true`, the event is found. `Curl` exhibits the same behavior.
The problem is that the `acknowledged` parameter is set by default to either `true` or `false`. And I cannot remove it.

As planned by zabbix api (I guess), if this parameter is set to `false`, all events should be returned. If the parameter is set to `true`, then only acknowledged events should be returned. But it doesn't work as intended.